# Updating array in java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm facing a problem with this code,please anyone can help me?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class A{
    int p[];
    int m,i;
    A(){
       p=new int[][10,20,30,40,50];
    }
    int sum(int p,int m){
       p+=m;
       return p;
   }
}
class B{
    int i,m;
    public static void main(String args[]){
        A object=new A();
        Scanner input=new input(System.in);
        m=input nextInt();
        for(i=o;i<object.p.length;i++){
           if(m==object.p[i]){
               n=object.sum(object.p[i],m);
               object.p[i]=n;
            }
        }
        for(i=0;i<object.p.length;i++){
            System.out.println(p[i]);}
        }
```

When i am taking 10 as input then it matches with the  first array value and then adds and becomes 20....But my problem is that when next time  i will run the program again,the value will not be changed(with adding results).......
how can i update the value of p array after the method for further calculation:?  ``

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you seem to have a matrix (2d array) p, and I can't see why.

Second, in your first for-loop, you have the letter 'o' instead of a zero. Typing error? (Copy-paste code instead)

Also, to save a new value to an array, just refer to its index, like so: 
`p[1][1] = new value;` (or what you seem to want: `p[1] = new value;`, but that's not the p you have).

Answer (score 0):

Store the result (after addition) in to new array. Hence your original array will not be changed. When you done with your method , you can store the result to the original array

Answer (score 0):

After exiting the program Java will go for garbage collection. So when you execute the program again the original array will be initialized. So to get the previous values of array you need to store the array into a disk. If you still want to use the changed value in array you can do it only during  the program execution, either by storing in a new array or putting the scanner into a loop.